# WHERE clause partly based on a field value from another table: is there a better way than exec with a dynamic string?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with about 50,000 records (a global index of corporate and government bonds).

I would like the user to be able to filter this master index firstly into a smaller subset index (based on permanent logic), and then apply further run time criteria that vary each time.

For example, let's say the user wanted to start from one of many subset indices of bonds, let's say of government bonds only, rather than government and corporate bonds, and also only wanted the US$ government bond index specifically.  This would be a permanently defined subset of the master index, with a where clause something like "[Level1]='Government' AND [Currency]='USD' AND [CountryCode]='US'"

At run time, the user would additionally request additional criteria, say for example "AND [IssueSize] > 1,000,000,000 AND [Yield] > 0.0112".

I initially thought of having a separate table that stored the different criteria for these permanent sub-indices as where clauses, for example it might have columns "IndexCode, IndexLogic", and using the example above the values would be "UST", "[Level1]='Government' and [Currency]='USD' AND [CountryCode]='US'", and there would be dozens of rows in this table defining commonly used bond indices.

I had originally thought of creating a dynamic string at run-time, where the user supplies their choice of sub-index code ('UST' in the example above), which then adds the relevant where conditions, and any additional criteria passed as separate parameters, and then doing an exec(@tsql) type command.  I had also thought of perhaps having a where clause that was a function call, but this seems very inefficient?

Is the dynamic string method the best way of doing this, or is there a better way involving some kind of 'eval' function equivalent which can take a field value and use that as a where clause?

Comment: TL;DR, see this [dynamic search conditions](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) article. I suggest either static SQL with `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` or parameterized dynamic SQL executed with `sp_executesql`.

Comment: @DanGuzman see my answer, what do you think?

Comment: @Charlieface, IMHO it would be better so separate the query from the physical implementation (indexes). Pre-defined filters, selectable or fixed, could be maintained in a user table if desired but indexes should be created separately to optimize common queries. There are many ways to engineer a working solution all with pros and cons.

Comment: @DanGuzman Depends. I have dealt with this exact problem: you don't want to rewrite queries constantly in order to hit a particular filtered index which has been changed. `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` has the overhead of recompilation on every run, this does not. And my solution still keeps the actual filter definition separate.

Comment: Thank you both very much - Dan I am going to read through your link in great detail, looks to be very much what I need.  Charlie I'm going to spend some time looking at your solution too, however as I am not a full time developer I must admit I'm no expert in indexes so it might take me some time to actually understand it to the same extent.  Thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you don't know in advance what the filtered index is.

A solution I have used in this instance, where the filtered index can often change is to grab the definition of the filter back into the client app, and use that to dynamically generate the SQL batch. You can also do this with dynamic SQL in a stored procedure:

```sql
SELECT ISNULL(
      (SELECT i.filter_definition
      FROM sys.indexes i
      WHERE i.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@tablename) AND
          i.name = @indexname AND has_filter = 1),
      '(1=1)');
```

You pass the table name, and the index name, and you get back the exact definition for the index. This has the benefit of if the index is dropped, the condition becomes `(1=1)` i.e. every row. You can change this to `(1=0)` to return nothing instead.

Then you concat this into your dynamic query like so:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE regular_conditions_here
    AND concated_filter_here
```

If you are joining other tables, I would advise you to subquery the filter, otherwise you many get column clash as there are no aliases.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM table WHERE concated_filter_here) table
JOIN othertables etc
WHERE regular_conditions_here
```